# Regexp for digit with decimal with maximum value

Tags: regex

I have a regexp to check for a decimal with 2 numbers, but I want to check both the integer and the decimal part for their length.

```
/^\s*-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,2})?\s*$/;
```

The above code is decimal with length 2 (ex: 12.23) but I want 10 integer value and 2 decimal value (10,2) like,

1234567890.12

Comment: You mean to add/adjust grouping? Something like [`^\s*-?([1-9]\d*)(?:\.(\d{1,2}))?\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/jQ1sE1/1)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `/^(?![.])\d{0,10}(\.\d{1,2})?$/`

It allows `1.23`, `1.2` `0.2`

Invalid values `., 1.`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you exactly want, you can use:

```
/^\s*-?(\d{1,10}(\.\d{1,2})?)\s*$/
```

for input like: 12.23, 3.4, 1234567890.34, 4, 456, etc., or:

```
/^\s*-?(\d{10}(\.\d{1,2})?)\s*$/
```

for: 9087654321, 1234567890.1, 1234567890.23 (10 digits, and optional point and one or two digits), or:

```
/^\s*-?(\d{10}\.\d{2})\s*$/
```

for exactly 10 digits fallowed by point and 2 digits, like: 9087654321.12, etc. Its all depends on what kind of numbers you want to filter.